# Printing out filenames of txt.-files that include at least one line of words, each starting with vowels. Only 1 line of code

Tags: python, file, listdir, one-liner

My task is to write only one line of code in Python. The code should do the following: I need to print out filenames of txt.files, which include at least one line of words, starting with only vowels (each word needs to start with a vowel from at least one line). My code is:

```
[filename for filename in listdir(".")if filename.endswith('.txt') and [line for line in open(filename) if ([word for word in line.split() if word[0] in ['a','e','i','o','u']])]]
```

I tried to use `os.listdir()`, but I am not allowed to write more than one sentence. My code also prints all 3 of my txt.files, even if one text file doesn´t include a sentence with words, which all start with vowels.

Comment: is it the filename or the sentence in the file that needs to start with a vowel?

Comment: The sentence in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following **one-liner**:

```py
print([filename for filename in os.listdir(".") if filename.endswith('.txt') and [line for line in open(filename) if all(word.startswith(('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')) for word in line.split())]])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['file3.txt']
```

---

## Test files

Tested with `file1.txt`, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`.

**file1.txt:**

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**file2.txt:**

```
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

**file3.txt:**

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Orangutangs appreciate apples over oranges and apricots
```

### Note

You can also use:

```
all((word[0] in 'aeiouAEIOU') for word in line.split()) 

instead of

all(word.startswith(('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')) for word in line.split())
```